# Can't connect to Postgres Docker container remotely

Tags: postgresql, docker, centos

I have a docker container running on a centos machine using the official Postgres docker image and it cannot be connected remotely. `sudo docker ps | grep postgres` gives

> 492192ff9170        postgres            "/docker-entrypoint.s"   2 years ago         Up 18 hours         0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   postgres

when I try `psql -h <server domain name> -p 5432 -U postgres` on the other machine, it just printed out

> psql: could not connect to server: Operation timed out
>       Is the server running on host [domain name] ([ip address]) and accepting
>       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

I did `sudo iptables -S  | grep 5432` on the remote server and it printed out

> -A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.2/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT

so it doesn't looks like `port 5432` was blocked

Inside the container `/var/lib/postgresql/data/`,
`host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5` had been added to the `pg_hba.conf`, while
`postgresql.conf` has `listen_addresses = '*'` specified.

Still, it cannot be accessed remotely, although I can successfully connect to the instance locally using `psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres`

Could any one shed some lights on this issue? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

How did you started the postgres container?

Probably you're only missing a container-to-host port binding option.

Try adding `-p 5432:5432` to your docker run command. This will map port 5432 in the container to port 5432 on the Docker host (your remote server).

See [docker networking docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/) for more information. 
See also [this postgres example](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/postgresql_service/) .

Comment: This did it for me, thanks! The links were very helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem, I was not able to connect to a postgres db in a docker container remotely.  I knocked my head around for 2 days until I discovered the solution.

I configured my ports in the following way:  `-p 5438:5432`.  In other words, I was trying to expose port 5438 on my host.

My host, as it turns out, was a Azure VM with Ubuntu installed.  And I finally remembered that under the "Networking" tab in the Azure portal you have a list of "Inbound port rules."

Well, I needed to open port 5438.  I did that and BANG it started working.  Wasn't an issue with docker config at all.
[image: Azure Inbound Port rules]